# Same method works in ViewDidLoad, but doesn't work in custom TableViewCell button action

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am learning iOS swift and creating an application to learn about getting JSON data and saving this data to CoreData while working with Itunes search api. I have a table view and am using a custom table view cell, it has some labels, an image and a download button. My purpose is to able to get album and all songs in that album information to CoreData after clicking the button of the cell. Here is the list of what is working and what is not working:

1. Clicking the button gives me the correct CollectionId for the album.
2. The album information is successfully added to CoreData.
3. I'm NOT able to fill my songs array after calling the api in my download action method. It stays empty. Note that when I call the api in ViewDidLoad with a manually entered collection id, the songs array is filled.

Codes:
API Controller to get the song information.

```
import Foundation

protocol songAPIControllerForCoreDataProtocol {
    func didReceiveAPISongResults(results: NSDictionary)
}

class songAPIControllerForCoreData {

    var delegate: songAPIControllerForCoreDataProtocol

    init(delegate: songAPIControllerForCoreDataProtocol) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func searchItunesForSongsBelongingTo(searchTerm: String) {

    // The iTunes API wants multiple terms separated by + symbols, so I'm replacing spaces with + signs
        let itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

    // Escape anything else that isn't URL-friendly
        if let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        // Using Itunes search api to find people that has a music album with the entered search term
            let urlPath = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=\(escapedSearchTerm)&entity=song"
            let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            println("Task completed")
                if(error != nil) {
                // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
                    println(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                var err: NSError?

                var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! NSDictionary
                println(jsonResult[0])
                if(err != nil) {
                // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                    println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                self.delegate.didReceiveAPISongResults(jsonResult)
                println(jsonResult)
            })

            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Song class (Not CoreData):

```
import Foundation

class Song {
    var title: String
    var previewURL: String
    var collectionID: Int

    init(title: String, previewURL: String, collectionID: Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.previewURL = previewURL
        self.collectionID = collectionID
    }

    class func songsWithJSON(allResults: NSArray) -> [Song] {

        // Create an empty array of Albums to append to from this list
        var songs = [Song]()

        // Store the results in our table data array
        if allResults.count>0 {

            // Sometimes iTunes returns a collection, not a track, so we check both for the 'name'
            for result in allResults {

                var title = result["trackName"] as? String
                if title == nil {
                    title = result["collectionName"] as? String
                }
                if title == nil {
                    title = result["collectionName"] as? String
                }
                let previewURL = result["previewUrl"] as? String ?? ""
                let collectionID = result["collectionId"] as? Int ?? 0

                var newSong = Song(title: title!, previewURL: previewURL, collectionID: collectionID)
                songs.append(newSong)
            }
        }
        return songs
    }

}
```

Finally AlbumViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AlbumViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, searchAPIControllerProtocol, songAPIControllerForCoreDataProtocol {

    @IBOutlet
    var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var artistNameOutlet: UILabel!

    var songapi : songAPIControllerForCoreData?
    var api : searchAPIController?
    var albums = [Album]()
    var songs = [Song]()
    var imageCache = [String : UIImage]()

    //Variables that take the values after segue from uTableViewController
    var artistID, artistName: String?

    let cellIdentifier: String = "albumCell"

    //for CoreData
    var error:NSError?
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
        as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.albums.count
    }

    func download(sender: AnyObject){
        var senderButton : UIButton = sender as! UIButton
        let newAlbum = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Albums", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as! Albums
        let newSong = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Songs", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as! Songs

        songapi!.searchItunesForSongsBelongingTo((String)(self.albums[senderButton.tag].collectionID))

        newAlbum.albumArt = self.albums[senderButton.tag].largeImageURL
        newAlbum.albumID = (String)(self.albums[senderButton.tag].collectionID)
        newAlbum.albumName = self.albums[senderButton.tag].title
        newAlbum.albumPrice = self.albums[senderButton.tag].price
        newAlbum.artistID = self.artistID!
        newAlbum.artistName = self.artistName!
        newAlbum.numberOfSongs = (String)(self.albums[senderButton.tag].trackCount)
        newAlbum.has = []

        println(self.songs)

        for(var i = 1; i < self.albums[senderButton.tag].trackCount - 1; i++){
            newSong.collectionID = String(self.songs[i].collectionID)
            newSong.previewURL = self.songs[i].previewURL
            newSong.songName = self.songs[i].title
        }

        self.managedObjectContext?.save(&self.error)
        println(newAlbum)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: AlbumTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! AlbumTableViewCell

        cell.albumCellButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.albumCellButton.addTarget(self, action: "download:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        let album = self.albums[indexPath.row]
        cell.albumName.text = album.title
        cell.artistImage.image = UIImage(named: "user7.png")
        cell.numberOfSongs.text = (String)(album.trackCount) + " Songs"


        // Get the formatted price string for display in the subtitle
        let formattedPrice = album.price

        // Grab the artworkUrl60 key to get an image URL for the app's thumbnail
        let urlString = album.thumbnailImageURL

        // Check our image cache for the existing key. This is just a dictionary of UIImages
        var image = self.imageCache[urlString]


        if( image == nil ) {
            // If the image does not exist, we need to download it
            var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!

            // Download an NSData representation of the image at the URL
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    image = UIImage(data: data)

                    // Store the image in to our cache
                    self.imageCache[urlString] = image
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as?AlbumTableViewCell {
                            cellToUpdate.artistImage.image = image
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })

        }
        else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as?AlbumTableViewCell {
                    cellToUpdate.artistImage.image = image
                }
            })
        }

        cell.priceOfAlbum.text = formattedPrice

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

    func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary) {
        var resultsArr: NSArray = results["results"] as! NSArray
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.albums = Album.albumsWithJSON(resultsArr)
            self.tableView!.reloadData()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        })
    }

    func didReceiveAPISongResults(results: NSDictionary) {
        var resultsArr: NSArray = results["results"] as! NSArray
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.songs = Song.songsWithJSON(resultsArr)
            self.tableView!.reloadData()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = artistName
        artistNameOutlet.text = " Albums"

        api = searchAPIController(delegate: self)
        songapi = songAPIControllerForCoreData(delegate: self)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        api!.searchItunesForAlbumsBelongingTo(self.artistName!, id: self.artistID!)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let songsController = segue.destinationViewController as! SongsViewController

        var albumCollectionID = self.albums
        var albumIndex = tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        var collectionID = self.albums[albumIndex].collectionID
        var albumName = self.albums[albumIndex].title

        songsController.albumName = albumName
        songsController.collectionID = collectionID

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: I would step through `searchItunesForSongsBelongingTo` and check if you are passing the right string. Try breaking up the line calling this function to see the various components you are assembling.

Comment: I checked and the right string is being passed. However after songapi!.searchItunesForSongsBelongingTo((String)(self.albums[senderButton.tag].collectionID)) call, the function didReceiveAPISongResults is never called, even though it should be. I just cant figure it out why :S Maybe there is a problem with delegate or protocols, I still dont have an exact handle on them, or maybe there is a threading issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the definition of your protocol like follows:

```
protocol songAPIControllerForCoreDataProtocol : class {
    func didReceiveAPISongResults(results: NSDictionary)
}
```

This will make it class only protocol and will force the confirming type to have reference semantics. If no 'class' keyword is specified it will have value semantics.

Without the 'class' keyword the issue here I assume is setting the delegate via initializer. When you pass delegate like:

```
songapi = songAPIControllerForCoreData(delegate: self)
```

This will assume the delegate param to be on value type and copy the value rather than send a reference of it. So when you set that value in init() the delegate member will point to a new object rather than the UIViewController passed.

If you set the delegate like:

```
songapi.delegate = self
```

it will work without the 'class' keyword in protocol definition.

Comment: Adding class to the protocol definition gave me the same result: after songapi!.searchItunesForSongsBelongingTo((String)(self.albums[senderButton.tag].‌​collectionID)) call, the function didReceiveAPISongResults is never called, even though it should be. Setting the delegate like songapi.delegate = self without adding 'class' keyword didn't work either. Now songapi becomes nil and it can't be unwrapped at the call songapi!.searchItunesForSongsBelongingTo((String)(self.albums[senderButton.tag].‌​collectionID))